# How to select duplicated items

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have a problem with

```
IEnumerable<SelectedProductRequest> selectedProducts = {
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product1", Price = 23},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product1", Price = 44},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 5, Name = "product2", Price = 11}
}

List<MyProducts> myProducts= {
new MyProducts{id = 4, Name = "product1", isExcl= true},
new MyProducts{id = 5, Name = "product2", isExcl= false}
}

IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel> products = myProducts
      .Select(product => new SelectedProductViewModel(
                            product.Name,
                            selectedProducts.FirstOrDefault(selectedProduct => selectedProduct.id== product.id)?.Price ?? 0,
                            product.IsExclusive))
                        .OrderByDescending(product => product.id)))
```

The products should return:

```
products= {
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product1", Price = 23, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product1", Price = 44, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 5, Name = "product2", Price = 11, IsExclusive = false}
}
```

What I get :

```
products= {
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 4, Name = "product1", Price = 23, IsExclusive = true},
new SelectedProductRequest {id = 5, Name = "product2", Price = 11, IsExclusive = false}
}
```

And that's because of the **FirstOrDefault**, Do you have any idea of how can I achieve the wanted result?

Comment: Based on the shown linq, what you get is as expected. You call select on a collection with 2 items, so 2 items will be retruned

Comment: Can you explain, what is wrong with your code? Have you tried to join both collections?

Comment: Yes the products collection is correct, but how can I merge selectedProducts to product with linq methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shown linq, what you get is as expected. You call select on a collection with 2 items, so 2 items will be retruned

Use a Linq Join on the id to get the desired output.

```
IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel> products = myProducts
    .Join(selectedProducts, product => product.id, selected => selected.id, (product, selected) =>
        new SelectedProductViewModel(product.Name, selected?.Price ?? 0, product.IsExclusive)
    );
```

Given that an Id is not passed to the view model, the order would need to be done before the join.

Comment: Thank you NKosi, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try additionally iterate through initial massive instead of FirstOrDefault:

```
IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel> products = myProducts
                .Select(product => selectedProducts.Where(selectedProduct => selectedProduct.id == product.id).Select(
                    resultProduct => new SelectedProductViewModel(
                        product.Name,
                        resultProduct?.Price ?? 0,
                        product.isExcl)))
```

Comment: Thank you but this will return a ``IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SelectedProductViewModel>>``